# I can't understand the logic here

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wrote a function to convert into PigLatin.

Result: gloveay

Expected: oveglay

First time when go through the function prepareCononants

```
   str      = 'glove'
   prepared = 'loveg'
```

Second time

```
   str      = 'loveg'
   prepared = 'ovegl'
```

Third time

```
 str      = 'ovegal'
 prepared = ''
```

The condition prepared.length > 0 is not met so it should return the str + 'ay'

but no, it will go back here instead to return into translatePigLatin function.
It will call the function prepareCononants recursively for 2 times more than I expected

```
if(prepared.length > 0) {
    debugger;
    prepareCononants(prepared);
  }

  debugger;//here

  return str + "ay";
```

---

Code:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  let word = prepareVowels(str);

  if(word.length > 0) {
    return word;
  }

 return prepareCononants(str);

}

function prepareVowels(str) {
    let vowels = [
    'a',    'e',
    'i',    'o',
    'u'
  ];

  return vowels.map((vowel) => {
                if(vowel === str[0]) {
                    return str + 'way';
                  }
                })
               .filter((word) => {
                  return word != null;
                })
               .toString();
}

function prepareCononants(str) {
  debugger;
  let consonants = [
    'b',    'c',
    'd',    'f',
    'g',    'h',
    'j',    'k',
    'l',    'm',
    'n',    'p',
    'q',    'r',
    's',    't',
    'v',    'w', 
    'x',    'y', 
    'z'
  ];

  let prepared = consonants.map((val) => {
    if(str[0] === val) {
      let word  = str.substring(1, str.length);
      word     += str[0];
      return word;      
    }})
   .filter((word) => {
      return word !== 'undefined';
    })
   .toString()
   .replace(/,/g,'');

  if(prepared.length > 0) {
    debugger;
    prepareCononants(prepared);
  }
  debugger;

  return str + "ay";
}


 console.log(translatePigLatin("glove"));
```

PS: I did another implementation but I can't understand the problem here.

Comment: Sorry prepared.length > 0

Comment: Then what do you mean by "back here"?

Comment: Your code as written outputs "gloveay".  It's not clear from your description what you're asking, exactly?

Comment: So when it will met the return str + "ay" it should go back to translatePigLatin function. This is the expected result, but instead it will come back into prepareCononants function on the Penultimate line (debugger)

Comment: @DanielBeck it should normally output oveglay. Run it in console step by step. You will understand what I want to say.That's why I left the debugger there. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say by "when it will met". Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: By the way, your `prepareCononants` function can be reduced to `function prepareCononants(str) { return str + "ay"; }`. That's all it does.

Comment: @melpomene I think you did not understand what the function is doing. I will explain here.
It is looking for cononants in the word. If it will find will put it at the end of the word, will do that until will find a vowel. The will append "ay" and will return the string.
Ex: glove -> oveglay

Comment: @melpomene when literally everyone you're talking to doesn't understand what you're asking, consider that the problem might not be with the people you're talking to, but with the clarity of your question.

Comment: @GabrielTerry Maybe that's what you want it to do, but that's not what the code actually does. What it actually does is `return str + "ay"`.

Comment: It is very hard to explain the problem here. I'm trying to do that. The simple way to understand the problem is to run the code in console, you will understand immediately.Thank you.

Comment: No, the simple way is for you to post a [mcve].

Comment: @GabrielTerry I believe I understand. :)

Comment: @melpomene I think I respected the  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Your code is not minimal. It's also only sort of verifiable because the only problem description you give is "it returns *thing* when I expected it to return *otherthing*", which isn't a targeted question about a specific part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
if (prepared.length > 0) {
    prepareCononants(prepared);
}
return str + "ay";
```

You're still performing the function again, but returning the first result. You should do:

```
if (prepared.length > 0) {
    return prepareCononants(prepared);
}
return str + "ay";
```

This outputs "oveglay"

Comment: Thank you very much, this was the problem. How can I accept this as the correct answer?

Comment: Happy to help! There should be a check mark around the upvote/downvote buttons.

Comment: Got it.Thank you again!